# PassPortjs setting local signup to use nested json

Tags: javascript, json, passport.js

Im trying to implement passsport on an old project and the scema's are set up to be nested for different things for example the name schema below is my sub schema.(There are more this is just for an example)

```
var nameSchema = new Schema(
{
    _id: false,
    "firstname"     : {type: String, required: true},
    "lastname"      : {type: String, required: true}
});

// Schema setup
var schema = new Schema(
{
    local       :
    {
        name        :   nameSchema,
        email       :   { type: String, required: true, trim: true, unique: true, select: true},
        password    :   { type: String, required: true, trim: true, select: true},
        regDate     :   { type: Date, select: false, createdAt: true},
        alevel      :   { type: Number, min : 1, max : 5, default: 1, select: true },

    }
});
```

But when I go to add this to my local strategy I get an error `TypeError: Cannot set property 'firstname' of undefined` How are nested json strategies implemented.
Currently what I have is:

```
 passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        aLevelField   : 'aLevel',
        namefield   : {
            firstnameField  : 'firstname',
            lastnameField   : 'lastname' 
        },
        passReqToCallback : true 
}, 
function(req, email, password, done) {
    process.nextTick(function() {
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {
            if (err){
                return done(err);
            }
            if (user){
                return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That email is already taken.'));
            } else {
                var user = new User();
                user.local.email = email;
                user.local.password = password;
                user.local.aLevel = req.body.aLevel;
                user.local.name.firstname = req.body.firstname; // <-- error
                user.local.name.lastname = req.body.lastname;
                console.log('after define',user);

                user.save(function(err){
                    if (err){
                        console.log(err)
                        throw err;
                    }
                    return done(null, user);
                });
            }
        });    
    });

}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just incase anyone also comes across this and cant figure it out. When I called
  `user.local.name.firstname = req.body.firstname` this from what i can assume was trying to access `.name.firstname` but because it was empty there was nothing to set `.firstname` too. 
To fix it do:

`user.local.name = {
                        firstname : req.body.firstname,
                        lastname  : req.body.lastname
                    };`